# JSX variable {MyX} in svg text rotate does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, text, rotation

I am trying to place rotated text in an svg window using the  tag but the rotate(90 100 70) will not take a {MyX} entry instead of the number 100, below is a small part of the JSX with a line that works, and the one that does not work. Notice that I use {MyX} in the earlier attribute and it works great. Why can it work in the rotate?

```
var w = 300
var h = 300
var MyX = 100
......
<svg width={w} height={h}>

//this line works if I put the x manually in the second parameter of rotate
<text x={MyX} y="70" stroke="black" transform="rotate(-90 100 70)">
    HELLO
</text> 

//this line gives this compile error shown below
<text x={MyX} y="70" stroke="black" transform="rotate(-90 {MyX} 70)">
    HELLO
</text> 

</svg>
```

//Here is the error in the chrome development window
react-dom.development.js:11720 Error:  attribute transform: Expected ')', "rotate(-90 {MyX} 70)".

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

```
transform={`rotate(-90 ${MyX} 70)`}
```

[More about template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @TommieBerry mark answer as correct to prevent other people from continuing answering, please.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, values surrounded by single or double quotes (`'` or `"`) are strings which don't support inline interpolation. Instead, you can either use the [`+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) to join two values like this:

`"rotate(-90 " + MyX + " 70)"`

or use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (`` ` ``) like this:

`` `rotate(-90 ${MyX} 70)` ``

Additionally, you have to use JSX's [curly brace syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (`prop={value}`) if the value is a JavaScript expression instead of a string.

Putting it all together, this would be a possible working implementation of what you want to achieve:

```js
<text x={MyX} y="70" stroke="black" transform={`rotate(-90 ${MyX} 70)`}>
    HELLO
</text>
```